# How do I capitalize the first letter of each word in an array of strings? Writing a `for ... of ... loop ` (ES6)

Tags: javascript

```js
const days = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday'];

for (const day of days) {
  console.log(day);
}
```

I need to print the days with the first letters capitalized...

Comment: This question had a specific case of its own since it called for using a `for ... of` loop to iterate over the data. I don't think it should be marked as a duplicate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply loop over the days and get the first character to uppercase like this:

```js
const days = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday'];

for (const day of days) {
  console.log(day[0].toUpperCase() + day.substr(1));
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to work this out with a `for ... of ... loop`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @JosephSsebagala ok check the edited answer. I changed it to what you need.

Comment: This has worked well, and thank you for the extraordinary help. 
This question seemed like a duplicate but it had a special case of its own. I don't think it should be marked duplicate

Comment: @JosephSsebagala Glad to help you

Answer (score 3):

```
days.map(day => day[0].toUpperCase() + day.substr(1))
```

Comment: Could you please add a snippet of your work-out? Thanks

Comment: @JosephSsebagala just have a look at ankits answer, he was so kind to copy it and put it into a snippet :)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps

```
string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the function `map` and the regex `/(.?)/` to replace the captured first letter with its upperCase representation.

```js
const days = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday'];
var result = days.map(d => d.replace(/(.?)/, (letter) => letter.toUpperCase()));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Old school:

```js
const days = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday'];

var result = [];
for(var i = 0; i < days.length; i++){
 result.push(days[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + days[i].substring(1));
}

console.log(result);
```